# Perl: Couldn't open encmap ascii.enc

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I'm running perl 5.8.9 in FreeBSD 7.4. And I'm using the XML/Parser.pm module.

It used to work, but today I got the following error message:
Couldn't open encmap ascii.enc:
No such file or directory
 at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/mach/XML/Parser.pm line 187

Any idea why the error happens? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII is natively supported by expat, so it shouldn't be looking for a `.enc` file for it.

> Expat has built-in encodings for: `UTF-8`, `ISO-8859-1`, `UTF-16`, and
> `US-ASCII`. Encodings are set either through the XML declaration
> encoding attribute or through the ProtocolEncoding option to XML::Parser
> or XML::Parser::Expat.

> For encodings other than the built-ins, expat calls the function
> load_encoding in the Expat package with the encoding name. This function
> looks for a file in the path list @XML::Parser::Expat::Encoding_Path, that
> matches the lower-cased name with a '.enc' extension. The first one it
> finds, it loads.

Maybe the XML document specified

```
encoding="ASCII"
```

instead of

```
encoding="US-ASCII"
```

The library doesn't recognise that they should be treated the same.

```
$ perl -MXML::Parser -e'
   XML::Parser->new->parse(
      qq{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="$ARGV[0]"?><root/>});
' US-ASCII

$ perl -MXML::Parser -e'
   XML::Parser->new->parse(
      qq{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="$ARGV[0]"?><root/>});
' ASCII
Couldn't open encmap ascii.enc:
No such file or directory
 at .../XML/Parser.pm line 187
```

Comment: Some clarification: There is more than one variant of ASCII. The only one in common use is US-ASCII. ASCII is usually taken to mean US-ASCII, but it appears that you must be specific when using expat.

Comment: A-ha, that's exactly the reason. Thank you so much.